# Can I run TableRowSorter from JMouseClicked and what's his sorting Algorithm used

Tags: java, sorting, jtable

First,
I want to know if it's possible to run TableRowSorter 'Or getRowSorter' using JMouseClicking 'By Clicking a Button' ???

The second one,
what's the sorting algorithm used in 'TableRowSorter' ? ... is it QuickSort or HeapSort ??

Thank's a lot

Answer (score 0):

You may find some useful tips in oracle documentation (How to use Tables)

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/TableSorterDemoProject/src/components/TableSorter.java

above may solve some part of your question.

Comment: Thank's Mr. stsd, but it's not what i want